# IOException The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I have application that run `Tshark` processes.
Each process create file (Wireshark file) on disk.
After the user decide to save specific file kill command set to the application and the process terminated.
After that `Procees.Exited` event raised and the file that just created copy to another location on disk.
at this point i want to delete the old file but in most cases got `IOException` that the file because it is being used by another process.

```
    private void CopyFile(MyClass tsharkFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string oldFile = ...
            string newFile = ...

            File.Copy(oldFile, newFile);
            File.Delete(oldFile);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            status = "Failed to delete file";
        }
    }
```

the above function being call after `Procees.Exited` event raised and the process not exist.
this is kill process function:

```
private void KillTshatkProcess(int processId)
{
    lock (_list) //
    {
        foreach (tsharkFile tsh in _list)
        {
            if (tsh.processId == processId)
            {
                Process process = Process.GetProcessById(tsh.processId); 
                if (process != null)
                {
                    process.Kill();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have some kind of way to wait and make sure my `Process` was dead and then delete the file?

Comment: It takes time for Windows to cleanup the shrapnel your Kill left behind, you'll have to give it a chance.

Comment: or maybe batter using Process.WaitToExit(2000) ?